# express error handling promises

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise

when jobs is null the error is handled but after it continues to the promises chain.How can i break the promise chain when there is an error?I use the default express error handler.

```
search.route('/:job/:lng/:lat')
.get((req, res, next) => { 
   Jobs.findOne({"names":req.params.job})
  .then((job) => {
    if(!job){
      err = new Error("Job "+req.params.job+" doesnt exist...Will look on it");
      err.status = 404;
      return next(err);
    }
    else{
    return(job.id);
    }

    }, (err) => next(err))
  .then((jobId) => {
   return( 
      Professionals.aggregate([

      { "$geoNear": {
          "near": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [Number(req.params.lng),Number(req.params.lat)]
          },
          "distanceField": "distance",
          "spherical": true,
          "maxDistance": maxDistance

      }}]

    ) 
  );

  }, (err) => next(err))
  .then((pros) => {
      for(i=0;i <= pros.length -1;i++){
        if(pros[i].distance > pros[i].location.radius ){
          pros.splice(i,1); 

        }

      }

      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json(pros);
  }, (err) => next(err))
  .catch((err) => next(err));

});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should not pass `(err) => next(err)` to every `then` callback. Catch the error once in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw), it's exactly for situations like that. When you create a new Promise, then you should use reject:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject());
```

Comment: i tried replacing return next(err); with throw "error"; and the problem consists